How to unset a variable which has dot in it
How can i unset a variable which has dot in it
for example:
s3.protocol
I tried to unset with the following command and i get the error
unset s3.protocol
bash: unset: `s3.protocol': not a valid identifier

env | grep -i protocol
amazon.s3.protocol=HTTPS
s3.protocol=HTTPS
elasticsearch.protocol=https


How did you get the . in the variable name in the first place? – Bash doesn't allow setting them up

Recommended suggestion would be find out the tool that set it up in the first place and unset it from there.

What makes you believe there is a variable s3.protocol there?

we use some custom tool to apply the env variables on all the running containers in the kubernetes and we ended up applying these "dot" variables and now unable to remove it

Show the relevant sections of the outputs of env and declare -p.

yes, bash variables

Can you show a few lines in bash that illustrates how this variable interferes?

@WeijunZhou
env | grep -i protocol

amazon.s3.protocol=HTTPS
s3.protocol=HTTPS
elasticsearch.protocol=https


Don't reply in comments. Please edit them into the question with proper formatting.

we use some custom tool - then change that tool, it violates the bash rules for environment variable names: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html#index-name

@Inian bash is not the only program that can consume or create environment variables

bash doesn't use environment variables directly. On startup, if it sees an environment variable whose name is also a valid identifier, it creates a shell variable initialized with the value of the environment variable.

If your variable appears in env, you can replace the current shell with another shell that does not have the environment variable in it. Assuming you want to remove all three variables.
exec env -u amazon.s3.protocol -u s3.protocol -u elasticsearch.protocol "$SHELL"

The env -u removes the specified variables before launching another copy of the current shell. I used $SHELL here for illustration but you should replace it with the name or path to your actual shell (which for example can be bash or /usr/local/bin/bash-4), or you can use $0 if it makes sense. The exec ensures that the new shell replaces the current shell instead of being launched as a subshell.
To also forward all command line arguments of the current shell and all the variables local to the current shell, some extra arguments can be added.
exec env -u amazon.s3.protocol -u s3.protocol -u elasticsearch.protocol "$SHELL" "$@" --rcfile <(echo ". ~/.bashrc; $(declare -p| awk '($2 !~ "r")')")

Where "$@" forwards all the command line arguments to the new shell (assuming shift has not been used directly in the current shell), and the $(declare -p) extracts all the bash variables in the current shell. The output of declare -p is passed to awk to remove readonly variables, then passed to the new shell via the mechanism presented in this answer.

$SHELL is the user's preferred shell, not necessarily the current shell process.

@TobySpeight True. So what would be a better choice here?

See How to determine the current interactive shell that I'm in (command-line).

I have read that, but still cannot help feeling that there's no bulletproof way to determine the current shell. The user of my command should explicitly specify it if they know better.

Yes, that's what I was going to say - I would recommend $SHELL here; it was just the explanation was incorrect.

Caveat: not all implementations of env support the -u argument.

You can use the -u command of the env command to unset variables and remove it from the current environment. It also supports dotted variables of the format above.
So for your use case, just do
env -u s3.protocol bash

The bash command at the last is to start a new login shell with the variable removed from the environment.
